# how to change QComboBox value by clicking button in PyQt4 (python2.7)?

Tags: python, button, combobox, pyqt, pyqt4

I am beginner to PyQt.
In pyqt4:how to change QComboBox current value by clicking button

I want

**Before click button:**

combobox current value is "C", before click button(like this image)

[image]

**After click button:**

combobox current value have to become "Java" After click button(like this image)

[image]

How can  I get this?
Please tell me with code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt has what is known as 'signals' and 'slots' to let widgets communicate with each other. A QPushButton automatically emits a signal whenever it's clicked. In your code you can connect this signal to a method of any other widget (this method then becomes the 'slot'). The result is that the slot method will be executed everytime when the signal is sent.

Below is a snippet of code where a connection is made between the QPushButton `clicked` signal and the QComboBox `setCurrentIndex` method. It should give the behaviour that you're looking for:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.init_widgets()
        self.init_connections()


    def init_widgets(self):
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton(parent=self)
        self.button.setText('Select Java')

        self.combo_box = QtGui.QComboBox(parent=self)
        self.combo_box.addItems(['C', 'Java'])

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo_box, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)


    def init_connections(self):
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.combo_box.setCurrentIndex(1))


qt_application = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
qt_application.exec_()
```